# SQL removes always last image

Tags: android, sql

I've a Activity which shows saved views, with data from a database (storage, ...).
I want to remove a file from the ListView throw onLongClick

**newest** file is on top

the log is correct too (position, ...)

but the every time the **last** image got removed

*noticed now: on OnItemClickListener is the same problem!*

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ShowClippingsActivity.this,
                ShowClippingDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ShowClippingsActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, position);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
    }
});

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            final int position, long id) {
        ShowClippingsActivity.this.removeClipping(position);

        return true;
    }
});


public void removeClipping(final int position) {
    // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            ShowClippingsActivity.this);

    // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog
    // characteristics
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message).setTitle(
            R.string.dialog_title);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //TODO BUG - removes always last image
            // User clicked OK button
            // Get the _ID of the clipping to delete
            ShowClippingsActivity.this.mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            int clippingId = ShowClippingsActivity.this.mCursor.getInt(ShowClippingsActivity.this.mCursor.getColumnIndex(Clipping._ID));

            // Define 'where' part of query.
            String selection = Clipping._ID + " LIKE ?";
            // Specify arguments in placeholder order.

            String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(clippingId) };
            // Issue SQL statement.
            int deletedRows = ShowClippingsActivity.this.mDb.delete(
                    Clipping.TABLE_NAME, selection,
                    selectionArgs);

            Log.d(TAG, "--------------");
            //Log.d(TAG, "positon: " + id);
            Log.d(TAG, "id: " + String.valueOf(position));
            Log.d(TAG, "sql: " + Clipping.TABLE_NAME + " | " + selection  + " | " + selectionArgs[0]);
            Log.d(TAG, "deletedRows: " + String.valueOf(deletedRows));

            ShowClippingsActivity.this.mCursor = mDb.query(Clipping.TABLE_NAME, // The table to query
                    projection, // The columns to return
                    null, // The columns for the WHERE clause
                    null, // The values for the WHERE clause
                    null, // don't group the rows
                    null, // don't filter by row groups
                    sortOrder // The sort order
                    );

            ShowClippingsActivity.this.mListAdapter.swapCursor(ShowClippingsActivity.this.mCursor);
            ShowClippingsActivity.this.mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
    });

    // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

**Clipping.java**

```
/**
 * This class represents a clipping.
 */
public class Clipping {
/**
 * Unique clipping id
 */
private int clippingId;
/**
 * Timestamp of the creation of the clipping
 */
private int time;
/**
 * Textual describtion of the clipping
 */
private String text;
/**
 * Title of the clipping
 */
private String title;
/**
 * Link to the source of the clipping
 */
private String deeplink;
/**
 * Flag to mark a clipping as bookmarked
 */
private int readLater;

/**
 * Returns clipping id
 * @return clipping id
 */
public int getClippingId() {
    return clippingId;
}
/**
 * Sets the clipping id
 * @param clippingId clipping id
 */
public void setClippingId(int clippingId) {
    this.clippingId = clippingId;
}
/**
 * Returns the timestamp of creation of the clipping
 * @return timestamp of creation of the clipping
 */
public int getTime() {
    return time;
}
/**
 * Sets the timestamp of creation of the clipping
 * @param time timestamp of creation of the clipping
 */
public void setTime(int time) {
    this.time = time;
}
/**
 * Returns the textual description of the clipping
 * @return textual description of the clipping
 */
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
/**
 * Sets the textual description of the clipping
 * @param text textual description of the clipping
 */
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
/**
 * Returns the title of the clipping
 * @return title of the clipping
 */
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
/**
 * Sets the title of the clipping
 * @param title title of the clipping
 */
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
/**
 * Returns the link to the source of the clipping
 * @return link to the source of the clipping
 */
public String getDeeplink() {
    return deeplink;
}
/**
 * Sets the link of the source of the clipping
 * @param deeplink link to the source of the clipping
 */
public void setDeeplink(String deeplink) {
    this.deeplink = deeplink;
}
/**
 * Returns the flag, which marks the clipping as a bookmark
 * @return flag, which marks the clipping as a bookmark
 */
public int getReadLater() {
    return readLater;
}
/**
 * Sets the flag, which marks the clipping as a bookmark
 * @param readLater flag, which marks the clipping as a bookmark
 */
public void setReadLater(int readLater) {
    this.readLater = readLater;
}
}
```

Comment: How is the removeClipping called? Do you provide the correct id?

Comment: I smell an off-by-one error... Where is "position" variable initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Use (I assume the objects in your adapter are of type Clipping):

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {
            Clipping clipping = (Clipping)ShowClippingsActivity.this. mListAdapter.getItem(position);
            ShowClippingsActivity.this.removeClipping(clipping.getId());

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The row id int you are getting from onItemLongClick is the index of the view in the adapter. It is similar to the position value, but accounts for views not necessarily backed by items in your list (for example a header view or footer view). In general, this index will not match the id of the corresponding database entry. When you call removeClipping you need to pass in the id that will correctly relate to the database entry you wish to remove.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
    // we have a view, but what we really need is the Clipping item
    Clipping clipping = (Clipping) ShowClippingsActivity.this.mListAdapter.getItem(position);

    // now we get the correct id that relates to the database
    long clippingId = clipping.getDatabaseId();

    // now we can prompt the user to delete the correct entry from the database
    ShowClippingsActivity.this.removeClipping(clippingId);

    // and lastly indicate that we handled the click event
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it's the row id which _we_ used

Comment: My apologies, I worded the answer incorrectly in that case. Row id in this case, is still not the id of the database entry however. Row id is useful for iterators that need to assign a unique identifier to each view returned by the adapter, even when those views might not be a part of the list that makes it up. For example, if you have a header view, it will be row id 0 with no position assigned to it. The first item in your list will be row id 1 with position 0.

I have updated the wording my answer in the hopes that it will be more clear.

Comment: well now using **postion** - in onItemClick is the same problem i noticed now

Comment: It is exactly the same problem. You are still using the index in the list rather than the id from the database.